# use custom mongoDB server instead of mongolab

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Today i started migrating from firebase to mongoDB,
I used this tutorial and its all up and running http://thejackalofjavascript.com/re-architecting-a-firebase-app-in-node/

When checking the code i see there is a mongolab link connected to the code,
mongodb://admin:admin123@ds061620.mongolab.com:61620/testsync

My question is: can i easily setup my own local database to use instead of this? and what packages i would need to do this?

The main reason for switching to mongo instead of firebase is the pricing, please take this into account.

Comment: The short answer is: _Yes you can_. Install local mongodb server and use the following connection string `mongodb://localhost/your_db`. If you need ODM, use mongoose, otherwise mongodb node package will be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but could you be a little more specific? Which changes i meed to make? Should i run the database in another terminal/file? Do i need to setup some things that mongolab does automaticaly?

Comment: [This tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-connect-node-js-to-a-mongodb-database-on-a-vps "How To Connect Node.js to a MongoDB Database on a VPS") might be helpful.

Comment: If you want to install a local MongoDB server, follow the relevant instructions for your O/S: [Install MongoDB Community Edition](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/install-community/). You can connect to local or remote instances using the official [MongoDB Node.js driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). I also recommend reviewing the MongoDB server [Security Checklist](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/security-checklist) for appropriate security measures to implement (access control, network encryption, firewall, ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, of course you can.

First, install mongodb locally, to do that, follow the instructions for the [distribution](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) you're working on.

Then, make sure your mongodb service is running. 


After that, on your database connection script, change the connection parameters. 
I guess that you have something like this on your .js file:

**mongodb://admin:admin123@ds061620.mongolab.com:61620/testsync**

Just to make a connection test, try to change it to:

**mongo://localhost/test**

After a successful connection, you can start to manage your database as you want.


As additional information, you don't have to specify user, password and a different port than the mongo's default, because you're using your local configuration, if you want to do so, you have to configure your mongodb server to make it work that way.



I'm working with mongoose ORM to manage a local database, and here's my connection function working.

[Mongoose connection to local database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO08t.png)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake, it is not mongo://localhost/test, but mongodb://localhost/test